# button offcanvas only show

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-5

I use bootstrap 5. I try open offcanvas, and dont hide when I click button again.

```
<button data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" role="button">Add to Cart</button>
```

when I click button agian offcanvas close i dont have.

```
<div class="offcanvas offcanvas-end w-5 @ViewData["Pokaz"]" tabindex="-1" id="offcanvas" data-bs-scroll="true" data-bs-keyboard="false" data-bs-backdrop="false">
    <div class="offcanvas-header">
        <h6 class="offcanvas-title d-none d-sm-block" id="offcanvas">Your Order</h6>
    <button type="button" class="btn-close btn btn-success text-reset" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Close"></button>
</div>
```

How to setting button by click a button again dont hide offcanvas.
only show when is closed.

Help me guy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can realize this using JavaScript and when pressing the button always showing the offcanvas:

```
<button role="button" onclick="new bootstrap.Offcanvas(document.getElementById('offcanvas')).show();">Add to Cart</button>
```

Read more about this [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/offcanvas/#methods).

Of course, you can also write a separate function and call it (or add some checks before, whether it is open):

```
<button role="button" onclick="showOffcanvas()">Add to Cart</button>
```

```
function showOffcanvas() {
  var myOffcanvas = document.getElementById('offcanvas');
  var bsOffcanvas = new bootstrap.Offcanvas(myOffcanvas);
  bsOffcanvas.show();
}
```

Good luck!